MediaMetadataRetriver's setDataSource always fails
retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)

This line of code keeps throwing exception:

could not access
android.resource:/data/user/0/ba.simovic.videoeditor/cache/editedVideo.mp4

I would get a video from raw folder, I would edit it and save the new video to cache.

Original video file path android.resource:/2131492864 Edited video
file path:
android.resource:/data/user/0/ba.simovic.videoeditor/cache/editedVideo.mp4
Transformation complete for file
/data/user/0/ba.simovic.videoeditor/cache/editedVideo.mp4

Then I would set data source and it would throw the exception.

Set datasource to uri
android.resource:/data/user/0/ba.simovic.videoeditor/cache/editedVideo.mp4
Fail could not access
android.resource:/data/user/0/ba.simovic.videoeditor/cache/editedVideo.mp4

Some of the code:
private fun getVideoFrame(context: Context?, uri: Uri?): Bitmap? {
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()

    val currentPosMillis = exoPlayer.currentPosition.toDuration(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    val currentPosMicroSec = currentPosMillis.inWholeMicroseconds

    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
        bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(currentPosMicroSec)
    } catch (ex: RuntimeException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release()
        } catch (ex: RuntimeException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return bitmap
}

I get the same exception when trying to set the data source as the original video as well, so I know for sure that they exist.
val videoUri = Uri.Builder().scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE).path(R.raw.diamond.toString()).build()

Button(onClick = { image.value = getVideoFrame(LocalContext.current, videoUri2) })

Using code from this answer How to capture a video frame Exoplayer android
I have the following permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


The URI:

android.resource:/data/user/0/ba.simovic.videoeditor/cache/editedVideo.mp4

is incorrect.
The scheme part ("android.resource:") works for app resources.
But the rest ("/data/...") is a file path in the internal storage.
Try to create the URI from the file that you have saved:
Uri.parse(File(context.cacheDir, fileName))

